# Encounter SparkException "Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.2.0 to do data processing. I am using Dataframe.join to join 2 dataframes together, however I encountered this stack trace:

```html
18/03/29 11:27:06 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
18/03/29 11:27:09 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.codegenInner(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.doConsume(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:155)
    ...........
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 10 GB
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I searched on Internet for this error, but didn't get any hint or solution how to fix this.

Does Spark automatically broadcast Dataframe as part of the join? I am very surprise with this 8GB limit because I would have thought Dataframe supports "big data" and 8GB is not very big at all.

Thank you very much in advance for your advice on this.
Linh

Comment: Please include your DF creation and join code.

Answer (score 9):

After some reading, I've tried to disable the auto-broadcast and it seemed to work. Change Spark config with:

```
'spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold': '-1'
```

Comment: I am using this 'spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold': '-1' but still same error i am getting , what else should i try ?

Comment: I am using 'spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold': '-1' config but still facing the issue

Comment: In my case the broadcast was not because of autobroadcasting, but BroadcastNestedLoopJoin. So spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold was not relevant. I had to change my join to prevent that. https://carelesscoding.com/2019/04/06/spark-gotcha-1.html

Answer (score 8):

Currently it is a hard limit in spark that the broadcast variable size should be less than 8GB. See [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/exchange/BroadcastExchangeExec.scala#L101).

The 8GB size is generally big enough. If you consider that you re running a job with 100 executors, spark driver needs to send the 8GB data to 100 Nodes resulting 800GB network traffic. This cost will be much less if you don't broadcast and use simple join.

If you really need to change the autoBroadcast limit, you can use the following config

```
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: -1
```

Comment: I am using "unionByName" but not join , why am getting this error ? where can check which join caused this issue ?  I am using this 'spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold': '-1' but still same error i am getting , what else should i try ?